# Making Div tags row by row inplace of appending side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code repeats inside the script code and creates a div for each repition
import_div.jsp

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 activa_append" id="activa_append">
        <h5>pickup date</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 activa_append" id="activa_append">
        <h5>pickup date</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 activa_append" id="activa_append">
        <h5>pickup date</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 activa_append" id="activa_append">
        <h5>pickup date</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Two_wheeler_gear.jsp
The import_div.jsp code is included in activa_append div element

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        Two Wheeler with Gear
    </div>
    <div class="card-block" id="two_wheeler_gear">
        <button class="toggle-visibility" data-target="#display_on_click">
            Book Now
        </button>
        <div id="display_on_click">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 activa_append" id="activa_append"">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```js
<script>
 $(".create-div").click(function() {
            $(".activa_append").empty();
            var limit=document.getElementById("activa_number").value;
            for(var i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
                $('#activa_append').append('<object type="text/html" data="import_div.jsp" ></object>')
            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYV7G.png)

I dont want the div elements that are newly added side by side ,
but i want them to appear in a new line

i tried

```
 $('#activa_append').append('<object type="text/html" data="import_div.jsp" ></object>'+<br/>')
```

but it also prodduces the same result.How to resolve this issue.

Comment: add `style="width:100%"`

Answer (score 1):

You can edit their CSS class to include:

```
display: block;
```

Note that divs hould be block elements by default so there is already a rule is place setting them to `inline-block` so you can find and edit that line.